# Unclear RF Schematic Reference for Power Amplifier Connection and Matching Network Properties

Tags: microcontroller, rf, inductor, schematics, impedance-matching

### Background

I'm trying to design a device with an STM32WL series MCU using the UFBGA-73 package. There is only one reference circuit given for the RF portion of the MCU in an [application note (pg. 6)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00660594-optimized-rf-board-layout-for-stm32wl-series-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and the examples given in the document use the same package, so the pins are identical.

There are 4 RF signal I/O pins, 2 for RX and 2 for TX:

- **RFI_P**: Positive differential input (RX+, 100Ω).
- **RFI_N**: Negative differential input (RX-, 100Ω).
- **RFO_HP**: Low power output (TX, 50Ω).
- **RFO_LP**: High power output (TX, 50Ω).

There is an internal "power amplifier" supplying from pin **VR_PA** which itself is supplied from external input to the **VDDPA** pin. The external supply for **VDDPA** is required to be full voltage (e.g. 3.3V) when using high power (**RFO_HP**) but when using low power **VDDPA** must be connected to a different supply (SMPS feedback, 1.55V).

The **VR_PA** pin appears to be connected via an "inductor" (no value ever given in any document) to either **RFO_HP** *or* **RFO_LP** depending on the chosen TX power level, but another [application note (pg. 8)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00660597-migrating-from-stm32l0-stm32l1-stm32l4-series-associated-with-sx12xx-radio-to-stm32wlex-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf) shows a configuration for using both power levels is shown in this image:

[image: both power levels]

The sole reference image of the schematic for the RF circuit used in an unreleased *MB1552B* reference board can be seen below. This board uses an RF switch for choosing either TX or RX to the antenna connector from an external input and is configured for using **RFO_HP** but can be switched to **RFO_LP** via "permanent" solder connections, assumed to be for testing purposes.

[image: RF matching circuit]

### Questions

I have two issues, one about the power amplifier connection to the TX line and one about the general content of the reference circuit.

#### 1. Component Function

Most of the components don't have values, so it feels like an educated guessing game to figure out what they're for. I've included a rough interpretation of what I think they might be for.
[image: Reference interpretation]

#### 2. PA connection to TX (choke?)

I plan to target 915 MHz operation, so if the inductor **L3** in the reference *is* acting as a choke to block noise from the PA I should theoretically be able to use the same inductor for both of the two transmission lines because the blocking properties would not be related to power level (assuming it can handle the power). I am using an RF switch for selecting the power level as shown below, using the same signal as changing the two other switches (i.e. control input at each "LP" into a switch in the image). Can I use a single inductor to connect the currently active **PA** to the currently active **RFO**?.

As a side note I have seen guidelines for the choke impedance to be 10x the impedance to 10x50 = 500Ω, please let me know if this is appropriate/correct.
[image: Possible Option]

Answer (score 1):

Quick partial answer with docs that have become available since your wrote your question:

ST has published a pretty good app note AN5457 on the matching network design: https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00690797-rf-matching-network-design-guide-for-stm32wl-series-stmicroelectronics.pdf

You can also find specific component values in the BOM for the Nucleo WL55JC docs: https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-mpu-eval-tools/stm32-nucleo-boards/nucleo-wl55jc.html and there's a schematic for a not-yet-published reference board on the ST forum:  https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000FzAd6SAF/mb1552b-board-stm32wl-reference-layout-bom-and-schematic-

Finally, there are sx1262 docs and reference layouts on Semtech's site.

I still found it a mess to track down all the details 'cause the docs are scattered, but it's not a wild guessing game anymore.